# javax.swing.GroupLayout растягивает JPanel

Tags: java

Есть JPanel, в ней JLabel, JLabel, JTextArea, JButton.

```
javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panel);
        panel.setLayout(layout);

        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(icon)

                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                            .addComponent(text)
                            .addComponent(but1)
                        )


                )
        );

        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                        .addComponent(icon)

                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(text)
                            .addComponent(but1)
                        )


                )
        );
```

Text это JTextArea растягивается почемуто полностью по вышине панели на которой он находится и выходит вот такой эфект

http://joxi.ru/brR6opxhQY33Mr

А если добавить еще и другие панели, то все хорошо плющится, как это можно подправить?

http://joxi.ru/D2PQo0nudkaa7A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все я разобрался оказывается достаточно

```
layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup()
                .addGap(10)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE, false)

                        .addComponent(icon)

                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(text)
                            .addComponent(but1)
                        )


                )
                .addGap(10)
        );
```